# How to generate UUID based on timestamp to check its expiry

Tags: php, cakephp, uuid

I need to generate a UUID based on timestamp to be able to check if it still valid or not. How should I manage the expire date? I'm using CakePHP 2.9 and there is a utility to generate the UUID, using `CakeText::uuid()`.

Comment: Why do you need the uuid to be based on timestamp? Let the uuid simply be a unique id and have a separate value for the expire-date instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that is right, I suppose to include the expiry date in some how in uuid, Is it good idea? or separate them will be better?

Comment: That doesn't really answer _why_ you need to do it. Without knowing the reasoning behind it, it's hard to say if it's a good or bad idea. But if you _really_ need it, you could just generate a new uuid and append the timestamp on it. Something like: `$uuid = CakeText::uuid() . '-' . time();`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I need to apply auto login, a user can click on website which will transfer him to another domain, he should be able to login automatically without re insert credentials, by sending this UUID as url parameter then resend it to Api to login

Comment: Then the expiry should _only_ be in the database, not in the UUID. Remember that if it's in the UUID that you get from the client, they could tamper with it

Comment: exactly, so I'm separate them, Thanks @MagnusEriksson!